# Apache Zepplin - Access to the underyling nvd3 charting options?

Tags: nvd3.js, apache-zeppelin

Is there a way to customize how a chart is displayed by using the built-in charting feature?

Just the very basics, like adjusting `x-axis` or `y-axis`, and as well to customize the labels.

Found is some `Javascript` and `HTML` using the `nvd3.js` library. **Is this the only way?**

Answer (score 0):

I had spended couple weeks read the visualization part of Zeppelin. To my understanding that customizing the graph is difficult without modify zeppelin code.

Instead of I found the `angular` display system provided by Zeppelin is easier to use.

[spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) is using the zeppelin display system. Adding easy modeling feature from Spark DataFrame to highcharts. It also support in spark-shell.

Using following docker command try out

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -d knockdata/zeppelin-highcharts
```